# characters are omitted in rdlc report

Tags: .net, report, rdlc

i have created a rdlc report (language arabic-RTL),used 'Arial font'.
in layout mode and when printing report, some characters  are omitted.some advice

Comment: see this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31657/Localization-of-RDLC-Reports-into-an-Arabic-Locale

Answer (score 0):

Dont use Arial font, use Tahoma.

Comment: thanks for your reply.i have tried but i am still facing the same problem.